# Images added shown incorrectly in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm adding some images from gallery and filling in some details like so..
[image]

Now from this, the first out of the 3 images and their data is shown in another tableview like so on click of a submit button...

[image]

Now again I'm going to my `ADD PRODUCTS` screen and adding 2 more images..

[image]

But now when I click the submit button, the image shown in the tableview should be the 1st out of the 2 images, i.e. the image of the waterfall. But the image shown is this...

[image]

While picking image from the gallery, in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method, I'm converting the image to `NSData` and assigning them to an array of type `NSData` like so...

```
      let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as NSData?
      self.appDelegate.mydata1 = data!
      self.appDelegate.mydataArray.append(self.appDelegate.mydata1)
```

On click of submit button I'm saving the `self.appDelegate.mydataArray` to CoreData like so..

```
         newProdObj.setValue(self.appDelegate.mydataArray, forKey: 
         "imageDataArray") //In the .xcdatamodel, imageDataArray is an attribute of type Transformable and custom class type Array<NSData>
        do {

            try managedContext.save()
            self.newProductDetails.append(newProdObj as! NewProduct)
          } catch let error as NSError { }
```

In the tableviewcontroller view I'm fetching this data like so..

```
newProdDetails = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [NewProduct]

            for result in newProdDetails {
     if let imageData = result.value(forKey: "imageDataArray") as? 
                  Array<NSData> {
                            }
                   tableview.reloadData()

        }
```

In `cellForRowAt` this is what I'm doing...

```
let dfg = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]

cell.nameLabel.text = dfg.name
cell.qtyLabel.text = dfg.quantity
cell.rateLabel.text = dfg.mrp

let arrayOfAllImageData = dfg.imageDataArray

if let image = UIImage(data: arrayOfAllImageData![0] as Data) {
            imageArray.append(image)
            cell.productImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        }
```

What am I doing wrong..? or is there a better approach...?

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you do not change cell.productImageView.image if arrayOfAllImageData![indexPath.row] is nil

```
if let image = UIImage(data: arrayOfAllImageData![indexPath.row] as Data) {
    cell.productImageView.image = image 
}
```

So here you must add else block

Comment: So what should be in the else block..?

Comment: something like cell.productImageView.image = _placeholderImage_, if you know cell is reused and if some image already set in cell and arrayOfAllImageData![indexPath.row] id nil you'll have old image